# Difference in accessing only last element from a list vs accessing a range up to including the last elements from a list

Tags: python, list, matlab, slice

Being used to work with Matlab syntax now that I'm working with Python this example is confusing:

I have a list for which I want to access its last element, lets say `list_a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

In Python I have to do `list_a [-1] = 9` when in Matlab I would do `list_a(end)`

So in my mind `-1` in Python means the last element, same as the `end` keyword in Matlab.

Then I want to access the last 5 elements from the list, including the last one.

In Matlab I would do `list_a (6:end)`. Matlab arrays first index is 1 not 0 like in Python, that's why I have to start with index 6.

In my mind it would be logical to do `list_a[5:-1]` since `-1` means the last item of the list as in the example above. However, this doesn't work in Python, because the returned result is `[5, 6, 7, 8]` So to get the last element of the list in Python I have to do `list_a[5:]` and leave a blank

I don't know why they decided to do this but I'm wondering if there is something in Python I can use like the end keyword in Matlab that works for both list indexing and slicing. Thank you

Comment: Also: `a[4:7]` is a different set of elements to `a[7:4:-1]`. Reversing the order also changes which elements are included. I agree that the MATLAB way is more intuitive in many cases. The Python way has a few advantages too, but I don’t like it as much.

Comment: this is a Python question, not a MATLAB question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When slicing arrays, for example `list[x:y]`, y is not included. The way python slices arrays is starting from `x` and ending at `y-1`.

Now, when you add the `None` keyword when slicing a list, python takes it as the end of list. For example, if I did `list[1:None]`, it would grab index 1 to the last index. Confusing, but that's how python works.

Leaving a blank is the same as `None`. So, in your example, `list_a[5:]` is the same as `list_a[5:None]`.

As for your question, you can technically use `None` as an END keyword in python.

Comment: Oh I see! Great idea. However list_a[None] does not yield the end value of the list

Comment: @VMMF use None when slicing. When indexing, you can use -1. Like I said, python is confusing